# How to show $\exp(tX)\exp(tY)=\exp(t(X+Y)+tR(t))$ with $\displaystyle \lim_{t\to 0} R(t)=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $X\in GL(n, \mathbb R)$. The exponential of $X$ is the matrix given by $$\exp(X)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{X^n}{n!}.$$

I need some help for showing the following result: $$\exp(tX)\exp(tY)=\exp(t(X+Y)+tR(t)),\quad t\in\mathbb R,$$ with $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0} R(t)=0$.

Thanks

**Remark:** I need this result for showing that if $H$ is a closed subgroup of a Lie group $G\leq GL(n, \mathbb R)$ then $H$ is itself a lie group.

Comment: Something is fishy here. As $t \to 0$ you have the RHS of your second expression go to zero. OTOH, the LHS should go to $I$.

Comment: This looks wrong to me : if t goes to 0, then $exp(tX)$ goes to identity so the right hand side is weird

Comment: @nayrb you're right, I forgot the exponetial on the RHS..

Comment: @BertrandR I've fixed it =)

Comment: Excellent, I now appreciate the problem.

Comment: This exercise eventually leads to the [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula).

Comment: Are you sure you want $tR(t)$ to be inside  the exponential?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the exponential map is invertible near zero, you can consider the smooth matrix-valued function $\phi(t) = \exp^{-1}(\exp(tX)\exp(tY))$. A computation shows that $\phi(0)=0$ and $\phi'(0) =X+Y$, and therefore the first-order Taylor expansion of $\phi$ is
$$
\phi(t) = t(X+Y) + tR(t),
$$ where $R(t)\to 0$ as $t\to 0$.  For a more complete proof, see Proposition 20.10 in my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (2nd ed.).

Comment: Thanks =) I enjoy your books a lot, they are very well written =) Have you already considered writing some book about fiber bundles?

Comment: Thanks for the compliment! I do have a partial draft of a bundles book in progress, but it's not clear whether it'll ever get finished...

Answer (score 0):

Or simpler $e^{tX}e^{tY}=(I+tX+O(t^2))(I+tY+O(t^2))=I+t(X+Y)+O(t^2)=e^{t(X+Y)}+O(t^2)$.

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the original question. Why is it possible to write $e^{t(X+Y)}+O(t^2)$ in the form $e^{t(X+Y)+tR(t)}$, with $R(t)\to 0$ as $t\to 0$?

Comment: @ Jack Lee , of course you are right. In my mind, the required result was $e^{t(X+Y)}+O(t^2)$. I must also use the fact that $\exp$ is locally invertible.